# Why does dbus-daemon take 1min:30s to start?

Tags: systemd, archlinux, dbus

```
$ time sudo dbus-daemon --system
real    1m30.111s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Barebone ArchLinux inside docker on ArchLinux.

D-Bus Message Bus Daemon 1.12.16

Tried `dbus-x11` from AUR, same. Every time.

**Edit/Details**: the `sudo` invocation above takes 1:30 to execute, but the actual dbus-daemon process is spawned right away, and continues to run during and after the 1:30, successfully (i.e. it works). Reason I need dbus-daemon? for `avahi-daemon` (more specifically, to be able to run `avahi-browse --all` and discover stuff on my network).

**Edit2**: seems even though 'everything works' despite this slowness (avahi, network service discovery etc), the container becomes dead slow. Barely running `sudo echo 'something'` takes 25 seconds (a figure perhaps related to a timeout of 25000 inside /usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf). Just like an infection. For what it's worth, after reading more, seems the frustration of needing dbus is not restricted to the world of containerization - plenty of articles/communities like [this](https://sysdfree.wordpress.com/2018/08/30/232/) and [this](http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Comment: I see the same happening even under Debian 10 (buster) in docker. I don't see any logging regarding this. I have no idea why. Maybe try `--syslog` and look in /var/log/syslog. But I doubt it.

Comment: I am also trying to figure this out in the thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288883/how-do-i-check-the-boot-processes?noredirect=1#comment2187990_1288883

Comment: Ok I think I figured my issue out, it was an issue with a non existent swap partition, you can check my thread for my solution, perhaps you can apply it to your issue. then again, my issue only appeared to be dbus when i looked at my boot process via `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Answer (score 1):

I hit this issue with various Docker images, but not always. I digged deeper in this issue and found an [interessting comment on the systemd repo](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/16471#issuecomment-662377106).

The images I'm currently working on had `systemd` configured on `passwd` and `group`:

```
$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd:      sss files systemd
group:       sss files systemd
```

Then I removed the `systemd` provider (`$ sed -i 's/ systemd//g' /etc/nsswitch.conf`) and the 90s hang was gone when starting with `dbus-daemon --system --nofork`. This was really a PITA to find out.

I could also verify that exactly this was the issue/difference for another Docker image I'm maintaining.